# Why this redirect rule doesnt work?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this URL

```
example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flare_get_counts&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Funix-tutorial-402-356-%2F&post_id=34&_wpnonce=8c7fc14726
```

to

```
example.com/unix-tutorial/
```

and for this i wrote this redirect rule

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flare_get_counts$ http://example.com/$3
```

But this rule is not working. What is the correct way to redirect this URL?

Comment: In `admin-ajax.php`, write `<?php if($_GET['action'] == "flare_get_counts") die(header("Location:/unix-tutorial")); ?>`. Much easier.

Comment: You've forgotten to match part of the original URL. What's the structure of your original URL? This particular case makes it hard to understand. Give more examples maybe. :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yeah have fun updating that project...

Comment: i want to redirect 100's of URLs in this format..

Comment: Awful advice from @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that is bad, because when you upgrade your wordpress, `admin-ajax.php` may be overwritten. It should be done with regexp in `.htaccess`

Comment: Try this: `^\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php\?action=flare_get_counts(.*)$`

Comment: @lolka_bolka: it doesn't work. Clean URL is embedded in the OLD URL with action parameter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mask characters you don't want to be interpreted as regular expression:

```
^/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php\?action=flare_get_counts$
```

Comment: It's not enough. There are more parameters after the `action` value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `RedirectMatch` to match QUERY_STRING. Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead.

You can use this code in your `/wp-admin/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-admin/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=[^&]+&url= [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin-ajax\.php$ /unix-tutorial/? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Make sure **this is first rule** below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: I want to to redirect many URLs with action parameter. Your solution redirects me to only 1 page.. when i change your code to RewriteRule ^admin-ajax\.php$ /$3? [R=301,L] and test it..i get redirected to homepage not to the original URL

Comment: How can you use `$3` without understanding what `$3` contains. **I want to to redirect many URLs with action parameter** You've provided only one example in question. Provide more examples to get better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the PHP / WP way to redirect an AJAX request:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_flare_get_counts',        'so27188591_flare_redirect' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_flare_get_counts', 'so27188591_flare_redirect' );
function so27188591_flare_redirect()
{
    if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'flare_get_counts' )
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/unix-tutorial/' ) );

    exit;
}
```

Comment: I want to to redirect many URLs with action parameter. Your solution redirects me to only 1 page I.E /unix-tutorial/

Comment: You can do a php `switch` on the action, and add other passed `$_GET` variables to the target url with `add_query_arg()`

Comment: ... and add the actions dynamically, of course: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $action, 'my_ajax_callback' )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Redirect 301 /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flare_get_counts$ http://example.com/$3
```

Hopefully this will help you.